# MACsec encryption feature on Cisco NX-OSv 9000 Virtual Software?

Tags: mac-address, cisco-nexus, mac, cisco-nx-os, nx-os

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus9000/sw/7-x/nx-osv/configuration/guide/b_NX-OSv_9000/b_NX-OSv_chapter_01.html

The above link only stated some examples of features which are enabled in the **Cisco NX-OSv 9000** *virtual* emulator software:

> For example, the following features can be enabled:
>
> ```
> feature telnet
> feature bash-shell
> feature ospf
> feature bgp
> feature interface-vlan
> feature nv overlay
> ```

However, it did not state if the MACsec feature can be enabled.
Does anyone have any idea if the MACsec encryption feature can be enabled on the **Cisco NX-OSv 9000** *virtual* emulator software?

Thanks in advance for any assistance rendered!